# Implement stack in such a way so that we can find out minimum in O(1)

Tags: java, c, algorithm, data-structures

Interview Question:
We want to find out minimum element in the stack.
So, implement stack in such a way it will give me minimum element at any point of time in O(1)
One more condition, Space Complexity for finding minimum element should be O(1)

Time complexity:

Push operation: O(1)

Pop operation: O(1)

Get Minimum element: O(1)

How to do this ?

For example,
push(2);

**Stack:**

2 <- Top

**Minimum:** 2

push(3);

**Stack:**

3 <- Top

2

**Minimum:** 2

push(1);

**Stack:**

1 <- Top

3

2

**Minimum:** 1

pop();

**Stack:**

3 <- Top

2

Minimum: 2

Comment: I am not sure if I am missing anything, but if you have `n` elements, you would expect a Space Complexity of `n` no? If you want `n` to always be `1`, then, at most you will have 1 item, in that case, getting the smallest would always break down to checking the first element, which can be done in constant time.

Comment: Space complexity with a stack is O(n) so that 2nd requirement cannot be met

Comment: well, O(n) == O(1) if stack size 1 xD

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: are you sure they didn't say to use a stack to keep track of minimum? like of an array or something?

Comment: Actually, wouldnt just having a minimum variable be O(1)? it sounds like their asking immediate cost, not overall cost

Comment: no array is allowed.

Comment: @Kevin: Read the title, Question is to implement stack in such a way we can find minimum element in O(1)

Comment: @user3078630 Questions end with question marks, and you should show the work you've tried so far.

Comment: how long do they give you to write this??? cuz if i was interviewing you and you took this long to write what seems like a 5 minute method, bye bye job opp

Comment: what did you end up writing??? and nice

Comment: When I came home and spent few hours on this question, I got some idea to do this. But first of all I want to ask this question here to know the public review ;)

Comment: There is no need to mention space constraints not below the corresponding time constraint.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the space complexity is innately going to be `O(n)`, but an easy answer to a question like this is just to make push and pop do more work and be more inefficient than usual.

So you add an `int minVal` to your stack and then any time you push or pop, you simply update the value relative to whatever you push on and pop off. So if our min is 1 and we pop 1, then we look for a minimum in the entire stack again. Same goes if we push a 0 but our min is currently a 1, we set the min to 0.

This makes `getMin()` `O(1)` but other functions less efficient - which still fits the rules of the question.

There are better ways to minimize the effect on push/pop of course, but it will blow up the space.

Comment: I feel that the whole part about having to search for a new min part can be easily avoided by keeping 2 variables, one for min, and one for next smalledst

Comment: @that-ru551an-guy, But then if you `pop` the smallest value _and_ the second smallest value, you won't know what to make the new minimum.

Comment: @Eric: after doing pop operation, if you find minimum in whole stack then the time complexity would be O(n).

Comment: O.o a stack to keep track of your stack ;)

Comment: @user3078630 yes... as I've stated already... but the only requirement is that `getMin()` is `O(1)`

Comment: and it would be... you only update your min variable when adding or removing nodes...

Comment: Means whenever i call to getMin function it doesn't given me answer in O(1)

Comment: no, user, you are wrong on that one. They aren't gonna call getMin and add a node in the same line of code are they?

Comment: @user3078630 check out what I wrote below... unless they said you can't have a secont queue

Comment: oh, I think they meant space complexity 1 for the min part itself, not the queue part

Comment: @that-ru551an-guy: yes only for min part

Comment: lol try to be more clear in the future, i was like trying to think of how d eff

Answer (score 2):

Annotate each element `x` of the stack with a secondary value for "minimal element below here", denote that by `mb(x)`. Then when you push `x`, you set `mb(x) = min{x, mb(element below x)}`, and that's all there is to it.

If that violates the space constraint (which could reasonably be interpreted to mean that only the operation of finding the minimum has to have constant space complexity and you can otherwise use as much additional space as you want, i.e. the space requirements for the stack itself are unbounded), then Eric's answer will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a minimum value and make another stack, one that keeps track of previous min values...

As for space complexity, im lost on how to pull that one off, unless n == 1, idk how you get O(1) space

Comment: make another stack means O(n)